# How to pass a more dynamic structure to jsp Spring Forms?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a structure:

```
public class Tabl {

    String tableName;
    List<String> tableColumns;

    public Tabl() {

    }

    public String getTableName() {
        return tableName;
    }
    public void setTableName(String tableName) {
        this.tableName = tableName;
    }
    public List<String> getTableColumns() {
        return tableColumns;
    }
    public void setTableColumns(List<String> tableColumns) {
        this.tableColumns = tableColumns;
    }

}
```

This form is emulating a table dynamically so to say. I have lots of simple tables with 1-2 columns except the id. I don't have an explicit assignment of fields as I have only one dynamic entity to hold them. The point of my question here is that I want to pass this tabl object and prepare a Spring form in jsp like this (I pass tableName from another JSP and it's ok:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addnew/{tableName}")
    public String insertForm(@PathVariable("tableName") String tableName, Model m) {
        Tabl tabl = new Tabl();
        tabl.setTableName(tableName);
        List<String> cols = spravochnikService.selectCols(tableName); //prepares structure by getting column names of the needed table (except the id): for example tableName=Employee, cols are firstname and lastname
        tabl.setTableColumns(cols);
        m.addAttribute("command", tabl);
        return "insert_form"
}
```

insert_form.jsp:

```
                    <f:form action="${url_csave}">
                        <table border="1">
                        <c:forEach var="col" items="${command.tableColumns}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <c:out value="col" />
                                <f:input path="col" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        </c:forEach>
                            <tr>                                
                                <td colspan="2" align="right">
                                    <button>Save</button>                                
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </f:form>
```

When I try to do it it says invalid property "firstname" and invalid getter method. I can't have an explicit getter for it of course as all my tables are all in one dynamic entity. How to make Spring Forms understand the structure?

Comment: The path attribute is bound into java property, as in your case the first column might getting name as "firstname" which is not a java bean property so it is throwing exception. remove `<f:input path="col" />`

Comment: Thank you, but what I'm trying to do is with the spring forms insert new values to the table, so I guess I need one or another type of input... Is it possible? So what I want is to connect to the filled structure and insert new firstname and lastname for example. If here were not employees but another table like companies or so, I want to achieve the same. Add other values to the table

Comment: may help you - [spring-form](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/)